# CASE statement with get date

Tags: sql, ssis

I get a file with todays date but sometimes this can sent through to me past midnight so it would be tomorrow between 00:00 and 03:00, Would a case statement work? If so can u help me with the code as I'm new to all of this. I think the case statement would need if it comes through between 00:00 and 03:00 it does getdate -1.

Using SSIS I get the package to read getdate() as a variable and thats how it knows what the file reads at.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to apply in ssis,**

An `execute sql task` will able trigger reading the file(s) on your folder based on the current date.

`select case when getdate() between cast(getdate() as date) and dateadd(ss, 30, cast(cast(getdate() + 1 as date) as datetime)) then 1 else 0 en`d

Comment: Thanks, I need it to read from a folder as a filename not from a table though. Not sure I've explained it well enough.